# python cPickle.dumps contain newlines

Tags: python, pickle

I want to save a `pickle.dumps()` result in file, one result per line as in the following example. Then when I load the line when I read the file, I found same result contains a newline.

Data, delimited by tabs:

```
20120305\txxxxx\t[the dumps result]
```

Would appreciate any help / suggestions.

Comment: I've edited your question to improve grammar and spelling, please do check I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `csv` module to output the file, and `pickle.dumps()` (save to string):

```
import csv

with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(['20120305', 'xxxxx', pickle.dumps(result)])
```

The `csv` module will take care of quoting; the newline will still be there, but with quotes around the data any proper CSV reader (including `csv.reader()`) can read the data again. Pass the data to `pickle.loads()` again.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! now i use python logging module handle this, i think csv module cannot integrate with the logging module, can give me some advice

Comment: I used the `csv` module to produce tab-delimited output that is tolerant of newlines in the data; there is little point in integrating this with the `logging` module. If the `logging` module works for you, stick with that.

Comment: pickle often adds `\n` characters into its pickling, so I have found it useful to put the `pickle.dumps(x)` into a list (i.e. `[pickle.dumps]`) like in the question in order to avoid problems.

Comment: @Roman: that'd break the format rather badly. The `csv` module *already* distinguishes between newlines in a column and row separators however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  If you read the csv file line by line (eg. in a MapReduce script), then the new line character causes problems.  Confining the pickled string in a list circumnavigates that problem.

Comment: @Roman: but then you'd have to first convert that *escaped* string back to proper bytes too. Whatever reads the CSV in MapReduce should be fixed to handle proper quoting instead, perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  I agree with you, though I could not figure anything more elegant out.  If the pickled string was not contained in something, the new line characters interfered with the csv reader.  I am also limited to the amount of code that I can change.  PS, I used `ast.literal_eval` to deal with the new format.

Comment: @Roman: you don't need to use a list here, by the way. Just use `repr()` to be explicit about what you are doing. Or `.encode('string_escape')` (although that won't include the quotes around the 'string').